# how to set an object/Property in 2D array javascript

Tags: javascript

Following is my Code i am trying to created a 2D array which must hold data in following format. `$scope.conditions.condition_set[$parent.$index][$index].response = "somevalue"`

but when i try to create my structure i get undefined index at

> $scope.conditions.condition_set[key][].message = "hi there"; // the empty array is throwing the error

```
result.forEach(function(key, index) {
   $scope.conditions.condition_set = [];
   $scope.conditions.condition_set[key]= [];
   $scope.conditions.condition_set[key][].message = "hi there";
});
```

Comment: What is `key`? You don't appear to be passing it into the function.

Comment: Ah let me set it please.

Comment: I was going to answer, but there are so many problems with this code. Syntax error: no closing bracket, key not defined, reinitializing the same base array on each iteration...and on and on...

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a property to array without providing the index. As I understand you can change the code to this:

```
result.forEach(function(entry) {
   $scope.conditions.condition_set = [];
   $scope.conditions.condition_set[key]= [];
   $scope.conditions.condition_set[key].push({message: "hi there"});
});
```

Then you can access the value like so:

```
console.log($scope.conditions.condition_set[key][0].message);
```

Comment: This works almost as i want , can you tell me whats wrong here?
`angular.forEach(responseMessages, function (v1, k1) {//this is nested angular.forEach loop
                                            $scope.conditions.condition_set[key].push({response: v1});
                                        });`
I still get array pushed into the 2D array, but for 2nd iteration i get `[1, Array(1)]`  as out put , why is that so. And is it possible to make it like this `[Array(1)]`

Comment: Please provide a working example (at least a complete function) because, as others pointed out, it's a bit hard to understand currently how the code should work and what should be the result. In this example I'm not sure what is the `key` field.